# Slow Performance on Duplicates Query?

Tags: mysql

I am running the following query to try and identify duplicates in my DB on a table

```
  SELECT *
FROM
  db.tablename x
JOIN db.tablename z
  ON x.columnA = z.columnA
WHERE
  x.columnB > z.columnB
```

However, it seems to be taking forever. i.e. just wondering whether this is a performance based issue or whether there is another way I can write this which will work faster ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to test, you can fetch only a couple of hundred records. For example

```
SELECT top 100 *
FROM
db.tablename x
JOIN db.tablename z
ON x.columnA = z.columnA
WHERE
x.columnB > z.columnB
```

Comment: thanks @razagill - tried this but getting an SQL error for the SELECT top 100 * [mysql 5.5] ? think needs to be "where .. LIMIT 100" ?

Comment: Oh, that only works for MSSQL. For MySQL you need to type LIMIT 100 after from table

Comment: yep :) LIMIT 100 :) thanks - think this is better idea and I can run this multiple times perhaps ?

Comment: Indeed you can, with varying limits. :)

Answer (score 2):

No obvious SQL issues.

1. Don't do `select *`.
2. What are the column types? Make sure that you're comparing apples to apples - ints to ints, for instance, in your where clause.
3. You're joining on a keyed column, right?

Comment: hey thanks for the response - yeah the problem is I want to the find the entire rows ... the reason for SELECT * - so once I can identify them I can delete them ?